# Characterisation of $\left(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)^{1/2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Let $T:=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ on $L^2([0,1])$ (let's say with Dirichlet boundary conditions). This is a positive operator and therefore has a positive square-root $\left(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)^{1/2}$

My question: Is there a nice characterisation of this square-root? I know that in $n$ dimensions the operator $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ is quite nasty, but I suspected that it might be better in one dimension.

It would be particularly nice to have some relation between $i\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\left(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)^{1/2}$. Does anyone know whether such a thing exists?

Maybe a more precise way to pose this question is the following: By the polar decomposition, there is a unitary operator $U$ such that 
$$i\frac{d}{dx} = U\left(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)^{1/2}.$$
What's $U$?

Comment: As Dirac operator, you get $i\frac{d}{dx}$ as one kind of root in the complexification of the function space. This you would also get from the square root in the Fourier series representation of the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $T$ has a complete orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions:
$$
              s_n(x) = \sqrt{2}\sin(n\pi x/L),\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
These functions are in the domain of $T$, with
$$
       Ts_n = \lambda_n s_n,\;\;\; \lambda_n=\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2},\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
And
$$
   \mathcal{D}(T) = \{ f \in L^2[0,1] : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n^2|\langle f,s_n\rangle|^2 < \infty \} \\
         Tf = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n \langle f,s_n\rangle s_n.
$$
The unique positive square root $\sqrt{T}$ of $T$ is characterized as
$$
      \mathcal{D}(T) = \{ f \in L^2 : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n|\langle f,s_n\rangle|^2 < \infty\} \\
         \sqrt{T}f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\lambda_n} \langle f,s_n\rangle s_n.
$$
Another orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,1]$ consists of the functions $c_n$ given by
$$
               c_0=1,c_1=\sqrt{2}\cos(\pi x/L),c_2=\sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi x/L),\cdots.
$$
The derivative operator $i\frac{d}{dx}$ with $0$ endpoint conditions is defined on $\mathcal{D}(\sqrt{T})$ and is given by
$$
                    i\frac{d}{dx}f = i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\lambda_n}\langle f,s_n\rangle c_n
$$
These differentiation operators are related by an isometry $V$ that is not unitary:
$$
                 i\frac{d}{dx} = V\sqrt{T} \\
                  Vf = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle f,s_n\rangle c_n.
$$
These differentiation operators cannot be related by a unitary $V$ because $\sqrt{T}$ is selfadjoint on $\mathcal{D}(\sqrt{T})$ with a dense range, while the range of $i\frac{d}{dx}$ restricted to $\mathcal{D}(\sqrt{T})$ is orthogonal to the constant function $1$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem probably is best solved in terms of the Fourier-series. If you want Dirichlet conditions on $[0,1]$, you should actually look at the Fourier series of 2-periodic odd functions on $[-1,1]$, however the length of the interval will just give you constants anyway. So for sake of simplicity I'll do periodic boundary conditions on $[0,2\pi]$ instead.

So if $c_k$ are the Fourier coefficients of $u$ in the basis $e^{ikx}$, then the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ simply translates to $c_k \mapsto ik c_k$.

In the same way, $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ on the Fourier side just is the multiplier $k^2$. But then it is not hard to see that $\left(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)^{1/2}$ translates to $c_k \mapsto |k| c_k$. (The eigenvalues are of the form $k^2$ with eigenfunctions $e^{ikx}$ and $e^{-ikx}$ each) If you compare this to $c_k \mapsto -k c_k$, which is $i\frac{d}{dx}$ on the Fourier side, you will see what your operator $U$ is in terms of the Fourier-coefficients, as it simply flips their sign for all positive $k$.